# Shared disks with COMPSs

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hpc, compss

I have a cluster which has a shared disk between the different nodes.

How can I configure COMP superscalar to take into account this shared disk in order to avoid file transfers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define it at the resources.xml

You have to define the shared disk in the root of the xml file with the `<Disk>` tag. There you have to specify the path where this disk is mounted in the master with the Mountpoint property. You have to do the same in the description of the different resources.

You can see an example in [this manual](http://compss.bsc.es/releases/compss/latest/docs/COMPSs_User_Manual_App_Exec.pdf)